# Counting difference in time between different rows

Tags: r, row, lubridate, dplyr

I got a dataset:

```
head(info)

     Person     Start              End   
1 Mark     06.08.2019 00:02:56 **06.08.2019 00:14:43**
5 Wendy    06.08.2019 00:16:31 06.08.2019 00:20:53
6 Mark     **06.08.2019 00:18:28** 06.08.2019 00:24:30
7   Mark   06.08.2019 00:20:26 06.08.2019 00:23:29
8   Wendy  06.08.2019 00:26:34 06.08.2019 00:32:41
9 Lenny    06.08.2019 00:31:13 06.08.2019 00:33:14
```

I want to have avg time of working for every Person, but the thing is I have to differentiate between END and START, but in the case for Person "Mark" it would be:

(06.08.2019 00:14:43)-(06.08.2019 00:18:28),

so not in the sam row but **info$End[1]-info$Start[2]** etc.

```
library(lubridate)
df<-
info%>%
  mutate(time = dmy_hms(`End`)-dmy_hms(`Start`))
```

would give time **info$End[1]-info$Start[1]**.

Next question is, what's the most efficient way to calculate that average time?

```
person<-
info %>%
    group_by(Person)
    %>%summarise(n=n())
```

will give me number of all periods for each Person.

So then, should I summarise by column **time** for each person and then just divide by this number of periods (let's call it **frequency**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tidyverse provide useful functions to perform operations on next/prior rows : `LEAD` and `LAG`. You first need to sort you dataframe.

Something like this should work (haven't been able to test it) :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  arrange(Person, Start) %>%
  mutate(time = dmy_hms(End) - lead(dmy_hms(Start))) %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  summarise((avg_time = mean(time, na.rm = T)))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is I was looking for ;)